# Constructing a customized matrix in C

Tags: c, matrix

I made some progress.Now the problem i'm getting is "warning: ‘mat’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]);" and is getting the "segmentation fault (core dumped)" when running.

Here's the code so far:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
   int **mat;
   int l, k, i, j;
   printf("rows?");
   scanf("%d", &k);
   printf("columns?");
   scanf("%d", &l);
   for(i = 0; i < k; i++){
     for(j = 0; j < l; j++){
       printf("mat[%d][%d]: ", i, j);
         scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]);
     }
   }
 }
   void prmat(int k, int l, int **mat){
        int i, j;
        printf("\n\n");
        for(i = 0; i < k; i++){
          for(j = 0; j < l; j++){
            printf("%d", mat[i][j]);
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: `int l,k; int mat[k][l];` is not possible. The values of `l` and `k` must be known before the matrix is allocated.

Comment: In the future, please format your code properly. People here don't like dealing with sloppy code. It just looks bad and is harder to read. It looks like you don't respect your readers or care about how you do things or really want an answer that much. Also, there thousands of questions a day here. People just want to look at the technical problem and try to solve it quickly if possible, so all the extra stuff about what you're thinking, designing, noobie, etc... is just a waste of time and makes the question longer to read.

Comment: Consider taking the [2 Minute Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [How Do I Ask A Good Question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

As DYZ said, we shouldn't give the statement int mat[k][l] without initialising l and k. By default, l and k has some garbage value which may create problem

Moreover you should have a prototype like below where k represents row and l represents columns
int prmat(int **mat,int k,int l)